# Forma adequada de manipular os dados recebidos do servidor

Tags: c#

Envio algo, um username por exemplo `writer.WriteLine(Username.text);`

E depois de tratar os dados no servidor, eu retorno algo como:

```
stwSend.WriteLine("a2|Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!");
```

E então no lado do cliente, eu espero com uma condicional

```
if(data.Substring(0, 2) == "a2")
 {
     var result = data.Substring(3);
 }
```

Estou fazendo isso bastante nos últimos dias, então me pergunto se existe uma forma adequada de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está construindo um serviço `Host`que vai trocar mensagens com seus  `clients`, o ideal seria usar como base os padrões já estabelecidos para esse tipo de operação, como `XML` ou `JSON`, você poderia pensar em aproveitar os recursos do framework e prover essa interação como um `SOAP`, `WCF` ou uma `Web API REST`

Não que seja impossível implementar da forma como você apresentou, porém ao invés do `substring()` eu faria um `split()` pelo `|` para dividir os argumentos. Tornando essa uma regra do seu modelo de contrato.

> {string código} | {string mensagem}

```
var mensagem = data.split('|'); 
if(mensagem[0] == "a2") //E demais validações
{
   var result = mensagem[1];
}
```

Da forma como está, logo você enfrentará problemas no caso de ter que responder um código `"a10"` ou se precisar aumentar o conjunto de informações enviadas ou recebidas como outros parâmetros além do código e mensagem. Essa prática ainda irá lhe trazer mais problemas caso você pretende distribuir o seu serviço para que terceiros façam suas próprias implementações para consumi-lo.